# Connecting 2 real android devices to PC

Tags: android

I have implemented the communication between 2 phones using sockets and tested in the emulator. It is working fine. However, when I m trying to connect 2 real android devices to my PC(both are getting charged from USB). But I m unable to view them in adb devices from command prompt/ in DDMS perspective. Please let me know, how can I do the same.

Thank you!

Comment: Check whether the USB debugging mode is on.

Comment: Thanks :) after enabling USB debugging mode, it is getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

May be you're missing usb drivers for your phones